# Trouble with react routing

Tags: reactjs

I have a master detail design in my project, with this routes:
localhost:3000/users (UserMasterComponent)
localhost:3000/users/register (UserDetailComponent)

When i call the localhost:3000/users/register, the browser calls "UserMasterComponent", so, It is ignoring the "register" at the url.

App.js

```js
return (
    <Router>
      <div>
          <h2>Welcome to React Router Tutorial</h2>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li><Link to={'/usuario'} className="nav-link">Usuario</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/usuario/cadastrar'} className="nav-link">About</Link></li>
          </ul>
          </nav>
          <hr />
          <Switch>
              <Route path='/usuario' component={UsuarioList} />
              <Route path='/usuario/cadastrar' component={UsuarioDetail} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a `Switch` from React Router, the path chosen will be the first one that satisfies the `path`.

In your case you are sending `/usuario/cadastrar` and the first option:

`<Route path='/usuario' component={UsuarioList} />`

will accept this.  What you are missing is the `exact`.  So try this:

```
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/usuario' component={UsuarioList} />
          <Route path='/usuario/cadastrar' component={UsuarioDetail} />
      </Switch>
```

For a good reference on starting with react router [check this out](https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91)